# MySQL insert into select data on duplicate key update using correlated sub queries with calculated field

Tags: php, mysql

1.**emp_ot**
 table use to define maximum amount of ot hours which employee can do 
within specific period

2.**daily_attend** describe what is actually happen

3.my tables shortened form as follows

```
mysql> select punchDate,empNO,ot from daily_attend;
+------------+--------+----------+
| punchDate  | empNO  | ot       |
+------------+--------+----------+
| 2012-02-20 | 000123 | 02:00:00 |
| 2012-02-02 | 000123 | 01:00:00 |
| 2012-02-01 | 000126 | 01:00:00 |
| 2012-02-01 | 000123 | 01:00:00 |
+------------+--------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select permitId,permitMonth,empNo,dayFrom,dayTO,permitOt from 
emp_ot;
+----------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+----------+
| permitId | permitMonth | empNo  | dayFrom    | dayTO      | permitOt |
+----------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+----------+
|        1 |          02 | 000123 | 2012-02-01 | 2012-02-10 | 02:00:00 |
|        2 |          02 | 000123 | 2012-02-20 | 2012-02-25 | 03:00:00 |
|        3 |          02 | 000126 | 2012-02-01 | 2012-01-10 | 02:00:00 |
|        4 |          03 | 000123 | 2012-03-01 | 2012-03-10 | 05:00:00 |
+----------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

4.here i want to update **emp_ot.workedOt** to know how many ot hours 
had worked under each **permitId** by employee

ex:

```
+----------+------------+----------+----------+
| permitId |  empNo     | workedOt | permitOt |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|        1 |  000123    | 02:00:00 | 02:00:00 |
|        2 |  000123    | 02:00:00 | 03:00:00 |
|        3 |  000126    | 01:00:00 | 02:00:00 |
|        4 |  000123    | 00:00:00 | 05:00:00 |
+----------+------------+----------+----------+
```

5.i'm using mysql event which driven at every day at 00:00:01 that 
because table should be automatically update without messing old data

6.my try as follows:

```
    DROP EVENT IF EXISTS make_emp_ot;

    DELIMITER |



    CREATE EVENT make_emp_ot

        ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS 
TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE,'00:00:01')

        DO

          BEGIN 

        INSERT INTO emp_ot( permitMonth,empNo, dayFrom, dayTo, workedOt)

             SELECT  o.permitId,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)AS 
permitMonth ,o.empNo,'','',(
               SELECT ifnull( SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(d.ot))) 
,'00:00:00')  

               FROM  daily_attend d

               WHERE d.punchDate BETWEEN o.dayFrom  AND o.dayTo
               GROUP BY o.empNo)AS ot

             FROM emp_ot o

             LEFT JOIN daily_attend d on o.empNo=d.empNo

             WHERE o.permitMonth=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

          workedOt=VALUES(workedOt) ;
    END; |


    DELIMITER ;
```

7.i suspect there were bad table joining and actually i don't want 
insert part, how to use only update part?

8.please help me to correct these things.Thank you every one.

Comment: In your sample data, is the `dayTo='2012-01-10'` for `permitId=3` a mistake?  It's both *before* the same record's `dayFrom='2012-02-01'` and gives the "calculated column" a value of zero in the join, instead of the `'01:00:00'` shown in your example output.

Comment: my example out put is not real one.i'm expecting result like that.
other two tables are real but in sort form there are more column not interested in this case.no mistake in emp_ot table .
permitId=3 is assign to empN0=000126 and permitId=1 is assign to empN0=000123 those are separated things.though i given an example sql code(my try as) also pls don't rely on it. 
i'm mainly expecting to get "how many ot hours had worked under each permitId by employee"  and i want to update those data to emp_ot.workedOt column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > i'm using mysql event which driven at every day at 00:00:01 that because table should be automatically update without messing old data

   Have you considered using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html)?
2. > i suspect there were bad table joining

   There are a number of problems with your `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement:

   - You specify only five columns in the `INSERT` part, but the `SELECT` returns six (I suspect you did not intend to `SELECT permitId`;
   - The empty string `''` is not a valid date literal for inserting into the `dayFrom` and `dayTo` columns (assuming that they are of MySQL's `DATE` type);
   - The `GROUP BY` within your subquery does not make much sense, as the outer query expects only one record: you should restrict its recordset to matches on `empNo` and remove its `GROUP BY` clause (all rows will be implicitly grouped by the aggregate function);
   - Since you have the correlated subquery, joining the tables in the outer query is unnecessary and erroneous (however you could achieve the same results without the correlated subquery by using such a join and then grouping the outer query, which would be more performant);
   - It isn't clear whether you have appropriate `UNIQUE` keys defined in order for the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part to function as expected.

   > and actually i don't want insert part, how to use only update part?

   Use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`:

   ```sql
   UPDATE emp_ot e
   SET    permitOt := (
            SELECT IFNULL(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(d.ot))),0)
            FROM   daily_attend d
            WHERE  d.empNo = e.empNo
               AND d.punchDate BETWEEN e.dayFrom AND e.dayTO
          )
   WHERE  permitMonth = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)
   ```

   See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9744/1).

Comment: first of all thank you for introducing sqlfiddle. emp_ot.permitId is the missed one in INSERT part.actually i want to update emp_ot.workedOt but in your case youhad done it to 
emp_ot.permiOt, 'emp_ot.permiOt' is the one assigned before employee attend to work therefore initialy i put all value to '00:00:00' in emp_ot.workedOt column, when employee doing ot system will catch their records and daily reprt it into  daily_attend table.after that event should be fire out and summing daily_attend.ot into emp_ot.workedOt column which relted to emp_ot.permitId considering daily_attend.puncDate

Comment: sory for the my ugly english typing